# Ubuntu 20.10 groovy-gorilla dual boot with puppy-linux fossapup

Tags: dual-boot, 20.10

How do we get Ubuntu 20.10 groovy-gorilla to dual boot with puppy-linux fossapup?

Comment: Ubuntu has an *install alongside* option, which achieves this easily.  How that option is presented will depend on what ISO you use (inc. if it's a *flavor*), but I would expect most users would have no difficulty.

Comment: How is this, and your answer on-topic? (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) as you're not detailing either Ubuntu, nor *flavor* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) and *Install alongside* is a pretty standard option in Ubuntu (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation) even if Puppy isn't specifically mentioned (it's just another OS)  SE's *Unix & Linux* would be more appropriate in my opinion anyway

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get groovy-gorilla to dual-boot with fossapup on Lenovo thinkpad t420s. Here are some observations:

1. When I installed fossapup, I did not get an option to install the distro in the entire partition. The option to install the distro in the entire partition does not exist anymore. You can only perform a frugal install with fossapup. In the past, I used to wipe out the partition, then skip installation of grub4dos, and reboot with [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to reinstall grub-2 followed by `sudo grub-update` which used to sense the puppy installation and bring it back. However, it does not work with fossapup.
2. When I ran boot-repair, I did not even get the grub menu because it was hidden, once I booted into groovy-gorilla, I had to comment `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden` in `/etc/default/grub` to make grub menu visible.
3. I found this post from 2015, titled, ["How to install Puppy Linux (frugal) and configure Grub2 bootloader"](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/579574/how-to-install-puppy-linux-frugal-and-configure-grub2-bootloader/?p=3735407) which was super helpful in fixing my issue. I followed the steps carefully.
4. The key step is the creation of `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file which is used to augment the grub menu. This is the key step. Please see link in bullet #3 for details
5. Once done, running `sudo grub-update` will inject fossapup into the menu. However, you won't see it when `grub-update` is running.

When I booted, I could see the fossapup menu item.

Comment: I don't see how this is on-topic (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) as you're not detailing either Ubuntu, nor *flavor* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) and *Install alongside* is a pretty standard option in Ubuntu (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation) even if Puppy isn't specifically mentioned (it's just another OS)

Comment: Thanks guiverc, all I want is share this information about dual booting with Ubuntu, and ask-ubuntu is a forum to ask and share information about our ubuntu experience. I have never used "install alongside" before so, thanks for that, I will explore this moving forward.

Comment: Ubuntu Forums (https://ubuntuforums.org/) is the Ubuntu Forum, this is a SE Q&A site (which yes is linked to the Ubuntu project), and whilst UF allows non-Ubuntu, this site is Ubuntu & official flavor only (except where it provides useful detail.. maybe others will consider you've provided useful detail & disagree with me, but I see it as mainly *off-topic* Puppy details thus belongs in SE *Unix & Linux*, but that's just my 2c). Thank you for sharing your *learnt* knowledge though!!  and have fun on your GNU/Linux journey :)

Comment: By the way, I just looked up ["install alongside"](https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-alongside-with-windows-dual-boot/). I have been doing this for years. I just did not know the term. So yes, I think I am aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, you can still do a full install of Puppy Fossapup by opening a terminal and running:

```
export ENABLE FULLINSTALL=1
puppyinstaller
```